# How to send cookie automatically from front-end with httpOnly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, jwt

I have a BE which is validating my sign in data then I am storing them in cookies like below:

```
exports.signIn = async (req, res) => {
const { email, password } = req.body;
const user = await User.findOne({
    email: email,
});
if (user === null) res.status(400).json({ error: 'No such user' });
let isCorrectUser = await user.authenticatePassword(password);
if (isCorrectUser) {
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET);
    // setting httpsOnly:true so that it is automatically sent from front-end
    res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true });
    res.json({
        message: 'User has been successfully logged in',
        body: {
            token: token,
            user: {
                id: user._id,
                email: user.email,
                role: user.role,
            },
        },
    });
} else {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'Incorrect password' });
}
```

};

I read that if we use httpOnly while making a post request we dont need to send the header with bearer token.
this is my auth helper in front-end to fetch users(only if signed in)

```
const newData = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3001/api/user/${userData.data.body.user.id}`,
        { credentials: 'include' } // could also try 'same-origin'
    );
```

But I need to specifically set bearer token from sign in explicitly  in the above request for it to work. I have read a lot of similar questions but it did not work. Please advise me how to work around.

Comment: Have you checked Dev Tools to see if you are getting the cookie from the server? Is the cookie included when you do the fetch()? What does the handler for /api/user/* look like?

Comment: So I can see a cookie tab in the sign up request, however when I fetch the /user tab there's no cookie tab. Also weirdly but the application >> cookie devtools is empty. I am not sure if thats ok though.

Comment: I am not very sure where it is wrong, because I am able to fire requests well in postman. so BE should be fine, not so sure why front end is not having the cookies.

Comment: I also wrote a route to return the cookie from BE to store it in react context, but even after passing `Authorization: 'Bearer <token>` it does not contain the cookie in res.cookie, where could I be wrong ? @RobertKawecki